# Get previous route URL : Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to get the previous route path in Angular. I have used this code below it is working when I am navigating from one route to another. But if I reload in the current route then the function below returning nothing.

Is there any way to the previous route after reload the current page?

```
import { Router, RoutesRecognized } from "@angular/router";
import { filter, pairwise } from 'rxjs/operators';

previousUrl:string;

constructor(private router: Router) {

    router.events
        .pipe(
          filter(event => event instanceof RoutesRecognized),
          pairwise()
        )            
        .subscribe((e: any) => {
            this.previousUrl = e[0].urlAfterRedirects;
        });
}
```

Comment: @ShashikantDevani, this._location.back() returning null

Comment: You can store the information in session or local storage, but either way that will break down when the user opens it in multiple tabs. Reloading the page resets the entire application, the router has no "previous" route at this point anymore, only the browser does, and that information is inaccessible due to security.